# custom post type link to page post wordpress twentyseventeen

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

so i am a complete noob at this but tried very hard and don't seem to succeed. Followed dozen of tutorials and it just won't work.

The **theme** that i am using is the **twentyseventeen**

Currently i am using this tutorial: [https://www.taniarascia.com/wordpress-from-scratch-part-two/][1] to create a custom post type in my functions.php. ( which succeeded) Thats done.

Now i have copied my pages.php and renamed it to: page-custom.php.
I have a **page** that is called "**custom**" in wordpress.

Also i have adjusted the settings to **permalink.**

```
**Now i use this code:**

 <?php
 /**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">




        <?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <?php
            $args =  array(
                'post_type' => 'my-custom-post',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
             $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="blog-post">
                <h2 class="blog-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); 
?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div> <!-- /.col -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>




    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer();


 **And this is the original code**


<?php
 /**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
  * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up 
the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer();
```

I can now create a post, but when i am trying to show it i get an error message:
" oops page was not found "

***How do i link the custom post type to a specific page to upload to?***

```
Here is my function:
**function.php**

function create_my_custom_post() {
register_post_type( 'my-custom-post',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'My Custom Post' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'My Custom Post' ),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'thumbnail',
              'custom-fields'
        )
 ));
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'create_my_custom_post' );
```

Comment: How do you access the page? By going to the view link of the `custom` page that you've created in the WP backend?

Comment: You created page slug or permalink must be custom and it must work

Comment: I acces the page by vieuw link. in wordpress.

Comment: @Junaid i acces the page when i go to post and then i go to vieuw link.
This is the link: http://localhost/sandbox/wordpress/my-custom-post/this-is-a-test/

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the 'Permalinks' page under Settings (/wp-admin/options-permalink.php) to get WP to recognize your post type.